# I m new to Matlab and currently working of weapon detection in images but i m getting false positives here.What should i do?

Tags: image, matlab

How can i caluclate the F1 score using matlab .This code is giving positive  results in negative samples also .I think thats because of dynamic background of images in datset. Should i change the dataset for better accuracy or change the approach .Please Help

Thanks

DataSet : http://kt.agh.edu.pl/~matiolanski/KnivesImagesDatabase/KnivesImagesDatabase.rar

CODE:`

```
TrainingSet = imageSet('Trainingset','recursive');

testSet= imageSet('TestSet','recursive');



img=read(TrainingSet(1),1);
[hog_4x4, vis4x4] = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',[4 4]);
cellSize = [4 4];
hogFeatureSize = length(hog_4x4);


trainingFeatures= [];
trainingLabels   = [];

x=  TrainingSet(1).Count;
y=  TrainingSet(2).Count;
for digit = 1:numel(TrainingSet)-1

    numImages = TrainingSet(digit).Count;           
    for i = 1:numImages-1

    img = rgb2gray(read(TrainingSet(digit), i));

    %Apply pre-processing steps


    features(i,:) = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);

end

%labels = repmat(TrainingSet(digit).Description, numImages, 1);


trainingFeatures = [trainingFeatures; features];   
%trainingLabels = [trainingLabels;   labels  ];   


end
negativeSize = size(trainingFeatures,1);
trainingLabels = zeros(size(trainingFeatures,1),1);

for digit = 2:2

    numImages= TrainingSet(digit).Count;           
    for i = 1:numImages-1

        img = rgb2gray(read(TrainingSet(digit), (i)));




        features1(i,:) = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);

    end

    %labels = repmat(TrainingSet(digit).Description, numImages, 1);


    trainingFeatures = [trainingFeatures; features1];   
    %trainingLabels  = [trainingLabels;   labels  ];   


end

 positiveLabels = ones(size(trainingFeatures,1) - negativeSize,1);
trainingLabels = [trainingLabels ; positiveLabels];

classifier = fitcsvm(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels);
classOrder =classifier.ClassNames;

img=read(testSet(1),1);


img = rgb2gray(img);
[testFeatures, testLabels] = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);

%Make class predictions using the test features.
predictedLabels = predict(classifier, testFeatures);
if(predictedLabels==1)

    warndlg('Object Detected','!! Warning !!');

else

     warndlg('Object Not Detected','!! Warning !!');

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using Faster-rcnn for the problem. It is one of the state-of-the art Convolutional Neural Network architectures used extensively for object detection task. [Here](https://github.com/ShaoqingRen/faster_rcnn) is a matlab implementation of the same.